# Get the HTTP/s clone URL for a GIT repo cloned using SSH in the first place?

Tags: git, ssh, tfs, azure-devops, git-clone

The SSH clone URL usually contains SSH port 22 on our version control server.
The aim is to get the actual application post.

For example,
SSH clone URL: ssh://host:22/tfs/collection/_git/project
HTTP clone URL: http://host:8080/tfs/collection/_git/project

Can I get the port 8080 using git as the underlying system? Any REST API requires this actual post to work on the system.

Comment: @rickvdbosch I tried fetching information about git remote, but the configurations included SSH URL and not HTTP.

Comment: @bk2204 Yes, it does. Thanks a lot!